"the tensions of the last WEEKS." OR "the tensions of the last WEEK."?
But we can bet that President Macron will now call for a period of apaisement – conciliation – after the tensions of the last weeks. BBC - French voting
The expression ".... the last weeks." caught my attention. Should it not have been "...the last week." as there can't more than one last week?

It means 'the last few weeks'.

What does the dictionary say? Merriam-Webster has an example with "her last hours".

"the tensions of the last weeks" is perfect English. The last weeks have seen an increase in crime in some neighborhoods.

+1 A good question. Why does a question get negative marking? And bad questions (with poor English and wrong grammar) gets ++

"the last weeks" should be "the last few weeks"

But we can bet that President Macron will now call for a period of apaisement – conciliation – after the tensions of the last weeks. BBC - French voting.

This report is probably filed by a Frenchman as the word "apaisement" is used instead of "appeasement"..

The expression ".... the last weeks." caught my attention. Should it not have been "...the last week." as there can't more than one last week?

There can be more than one last week. But the phrase should be "last two weeks" or "last few weeks". It could also mean "the last week's tensions"..
So it is wrong to say "the last weeks" as how many weeks is not mentioned.

I don't think it's wrong. A native speaker understands it to mean 'the last [period of several] weeks'. It's common to speak of 'the last days of [an institution or a period of history]'.

@KateBunting Last' by itself is only used for one week/month/year: Last week I was doing it. For more than one, use 'in the last few weeks' or 'in recent weeks' or 'over the last few weeks'. These need perfect tense: Over the last few weeks I have been thinking about you.
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/is-it-last-weeks-or-in-the-last-weeks.2055646/#:~:text='Last'%20by%20itself%20is%20only,have%20been%20thinking%20about%20you.

But this is the last weeks, not last week.

No, it's fine as is.

Also @JamesMathai, your comment about the perfect tense is wrong. Perfect tense can be used, but so can other tenses. Over the last few weeks I thought about you several times. Or, Over the last few weeks I was thinking about you often. Context is everything when it comes to tenses.

I'm not sure it's wrong, but I agree that adding "couple/few/several" or specifying a number sounds more idiomatic to me. And not just for "weeks", but for "days/months/years", too. @Lambie Perhaps this is a dialectal difference? Your English dialect might not line up with James' or mine.

@cmw The question is taken from BBC journalese. Adding numbers or whatever is not "more idiomatic"; it's different.  I find that many of these questions questioning perfectly good sources to be slighlty annoying.

@Lambie Surely you must agree that BBC journalese is completely different from everyday speech, let alone everyday speech in the US.

@cmw Also you won't find 'apaisement' in an English dictionary as it's a French word.

@PeterKirkpatrick The comment is not applicable to the OP. Reference is given from where it's taken.

@JamesMathai, I'm aware that I responded to your comment, not the OP. But what you said in that comment is wrong (as is the reference you quoted), as I showed by giving examples of how other tenses could be used. I felt that was necessary to point that out for other people who were reading this.

Since the writer adds the translation 'conciliation', they are obviously quoting the French term that is being used - it should have been printed in italics.

@cmw No, I don't agree at all that BBC news reporting language is completely different from everyday speech and US news reporting language. The main BrE/AmE differences being mostly elevator/lift-type stuff. And not things like "in the last years".

@Lambie That has not been my experience as an American English speaker. I've heard "these last weeks" but not "the last weeks" used in this way. I say "heard", by the way, for good reason.

in the last weeks can mean "in recent weeks".

Temperatures in the last weeks have been well above average for this time of year.

"in the last weeks" can also mean "in the final weeks" when the phrase is modified to say "... in the last weeks of {something with a known duration}"

Fetal position normally shifts in the last weeks of pregnancy.
In the last weeks of their term most presidents issue pardons.


This is a funny one. As a native English speaker, "the tension of the last weeks" just sounds wrong to me. But I can't say that "last weeks" is wrong, because if someone said, "He spent his last weeks saying goodbye to family and friends", that would be perfectly okay.
As @JamesMatthai says, normally we say "last two weeks" or "last few weeks" or put some number or indication of how many weeks in there. We don't just say "the last weeks". But I'm hard pressed to say what the rule is. The safe thing to do is put a number, or some placeholder for a number like "few" or "several", in there.

The last weeks have been difficult for them. We do just say "the last weeks", the last hours, the last  years. whatever.
